# I am a treasure with gold inside

Tags: riddle, word

I am a treasure with gold inside, protected by snow. My walls protect me from being caught. Taking all might not be so good for your health. I'd rather recommend the snow.

What might I be?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are

> an egg

The gold treasure is the

> yolk

protected by the snow

> the egg white which is said to be healthier than the yolk.

Comment: +1 Correct! The yolk is known for it's overdose of cholesterol that it holds.

Comment: Personally I don't subscribe to the idea of eggs being unhealthy. A quick google search for "are eggs unhealthy" turns up plenty of results that suggest it is a myth.

Comment: Because they aren't as a whole. Overdosing cholesterol from one egg isn't unhealthy. Yet the intake of more than 3~4 eggs per week is unadvised. But it's just the general idea and it might be controversial. So sorry for that :)

Comment: I heard that was based on out of date health advice and that cholestrol consumed was a small factor in blood cholestrol. http://skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/1186/is-eating-eggs-bad-for-me