# In marble halls

Tags: riddle

I noticed that puzzling stack exchange didn't have my favorite riddle. It isn't too uncommon so someone else might have heard it (and a quick google search can easily find the answer) but someone out there might enjoy it as much as I do. So here it is:

> In a marble hall white as milk,
>
> lined with skin as soft as silk.
>
> Within a fountain crystal-clear,
>
> a golden apple doth appear.
>
> No doors there are to this stronghold,
>
> yet thieves break in to steal its gold.
>
> What is it?

Hint:

> "thieves" is a strong word. If a person owns the marble hall then they also own the gold.

Comment: Not sure if [this](http://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/14631/i-am-a-treasure-with-gold-inside?rq=1) is similar enough to be called a duplicate?

Comment: @randal'thor I wouldn't think of this as a duplicate. They have the same answer but are different riddles.

Comment: A lot of the clues are similar too... I see your point though, which is why I haven't actually voted to close.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is this simply:

> An egg

In a marble hall white as milk,

> The eggshell

lined with skin as soft as silk.

> Whatever the skin inside the shell is called

Within a fountain crystal-clear,

> The white of the egg is clear(ish)

a golden apple doth appear.

> The yolk

No doors there are to this stronghold,

> No doors in an egg

yet thieves break in to steal its gold.

> Birds and other predators will prefer to eat the yolk

Comment: Your last point was insightful: I didn't know some animals did that. The riddle makes more sense to me now.